# Unity Client doesn't load online scene, Using: Unity3d new networking system, c#, Android, wifi

Tags: c#, android, networking, unity-game-engine, wifi

I have re-asked this question so as to be more specific. My second (client) android device will not load the online scene as selected in the network manager in the inspector. This works on pc, but when I transfer it to android it fails to do anything. I have properly attached network identities, a network manager, and a network HUD. They are on the same network running the same program, the host auto-spawn works, the prefab looks ok but i'm still stumped, and am using adb to try to find a solution. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Just to get you right: your second Android device doesn't? So, your first Android device does?

Comment: Yes. By the first, I should have said the first one i turn on. IE the host. And the client does nothing. I dont think i can get anything more from adb.

Comment: And are you sure the scene is not loaded? Did you for example let it have a different background color, so you can say for sure? If it really really doesn't load: is the connection from client to host definately established?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Hilbert . Yes the scene has a different background skybox. The connection im not sure about. How would I fix the connection?

Comment: Before you can fix you must know. NetworkManagerHud should tell you if the client is connected.

Comment: Thank you - well it says client initialised after i click on client ready, i would put in a debug.log line but I dont want to mess w the source code. Are therer other methods of debugging? Please Advise.

Comment: Im pretty sure the DONT connect